# How does UITableViewController knows its dataSource and delegate

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview

I am following the BigNerdRanch iOS Programming book and I am on this one chapter that deals with UITableViewController. I have been wondering however where `UITableViewController` finds out about its `delegate` and `dataSource`. Currently I have it as

`@interface ItemsViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>`

But there is nothing that looks like:

`[self.tableView setDelegate:self]`

I am just wondering how the UITableViewController finds out about its delegate and dataSource

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you were setting up the `UITableView` yourself, you would have to point it to a delegate and data source.

`UITableViewController` sets up the `UITableView` and sets the delegate and dataSource properties to itself. When you subclass `UITableViewController`, you get this behavior for free.

Your question is flawed because `UITableViewController` doesn't have a dataSource and delegate, the `UITableView` it is controlling does. And the `UITableViewController` is the dataSource and delegate because it sets things up that way.

Answer (score 1):

You either set the delegate and dataSource on the table view object (in the xib or storyboard file) via Interface Builder (within Xcode) or programatically, via ["`.delegate =`" (`[self.tableView setDelegate: _____`)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/delegate) and ["`.datasource=`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/dataSource).

Note, you're setting these things on the table view managed by the table view controller (i.e. two distinct objects).

Answer (score 1):

First of all the declaration:

```
@interface ItemsViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

**is only an indication** that your View Controller is responsible for providing DataSource and Delegate methods.
This is just an hint (you are just saying that your view is conforming to that protocols) to someone viewing your code and a hint to Xcode that you need to provided the required protocol implementations (else Xcode will give you a warning that you haven't implemented the datasource and delegate methods, and again only for the required and not optional methods).

You actually are setting the datasource and delegate of the TableView in the Interface Builder.
Click on the TableView in IB, select from the right pane the Outlets option, then click on datasource and drag over to the "File's Owner" to set the datasource.
Same for the delegate.

If you are creating the table in code, you need to declare the datasource and delegate yourself, this way:

```
tableview.datasource = self;
tableview.delegate = self;
```